# Issues with loaded package in R

Tags: r, r-package

I loaded the package "Poliscidata" for my research work in political science. But when I ran this library now, I find an error message like

```
library(poliscidata)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘poliscidata’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘stringi’.
```

It looks the package is not loading in my workspace. Kindly, let me know what should I do to run the package normally as before.

Comment: Did you try `install.packages("stringi")` ?

Comment: Thank you. I installed the 'stringi' package and now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`install.packages("stringi")`